# Determine subnet/cidr from start ip and broadcast ip

Tags: java, networking, ipv4

I searched in `apache commons netutils` and other known APIs, but couldn't find a good way to do this. 
Given an start `ip` and `broadcast` how to find the `subnet` or `cidr`.

I know `broadcast = ip | ( ~ subnet )`

But given start ip and broadcast ip , how to find the subnet.

For example start ip = 10.2.22.1 and getway/broadcast ip = 10.2.22.255.

`CIDR` format is `10.2.22.0/24` or `netmask` is `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: Your title text doesn't match your question text. Which items do you actually have and which are you looking for?

Comment: Come on! Make IP and subnet a reasonable Number and the '|' should work. Don't forget making the ips to Strings afterwards... - just inserting some dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do this.

```
Integer cidrSize = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(startIpInteger ^ broadcastIpInteger);
String cidrNotation = startIpString/cidrSize;
```

How to get integer representation of an IP ? 
[Apache commons net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo.html#asInteger%28java.lang.String%29) can help

Now getting netmask can be as simple as

```
SubnetInfo info = new SubnetUtils(cidrNotation).getInfo();
String netmask = info.getNetmask();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
int ip2Num(final String ip) {
    int result = 0;
    final String[] segs = ip.split("\\.");
    int c = 32;
    for (final String s : segs) {
        result |= Integer.parseInt(s) << c;
        c -= 8;
    }
    return result;
}
// not used at that moment
String long2Ip(final int l) {
    String result = "" + l;
    result = result.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{3})(\\d{3})", ".$1");
    return result;
}
void sendIfMatch(final String ip, final String netmask) {
    final int lIp = ip2Num(ip);
    final int lNm = ip2Num(netmask);
    final boolean matches = ((lIp & lNm) == lIp);
    if (matches) {
        System.out.println("we should do something for ip " + ip);
    } else {
        System.out.println("dont match: " + lIp + "::" + lNm);
    }
}
void test() {
    sendIfMatch("10.2.22.1", "10.2.22.255");
}
```